# How to update a type of a realm model property in Objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm, realm-migration

I have a RLMObject in my Objective-c. I defined a property like:

```
 @property (assign, nonatomic) NSString *name;
 @property (assign, nonatomic) NSString *code;
 @property (assign, nonatomic) int day;
 @property (assign, nonatomic) int status;
```

But now, I need change the type of property code to int like:

```
 @property (assign, nonatomic) int code;
```

If I change this, then when I try access to the model I get an error showing that type was NSString and now int.

How can I change the property without reinstall my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to perform a migration so the data in the database fits the new data model. Please check the [Migrations](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#migrations) section of the Realm documentation.

Comment: Exactly with the first example on the Migrations section of the Realm documentation I got update my model. Thanks!